# Correction for autocorrelation in segmented regression - is this analysis legitemate?

Tags: autocorrelation, segmented-regression

For a project, I want to investigate the effect of an intervention on rates per year through segmented regression.

```
model <- lm(rate ~ time + int + tsi, 
                data = data)
# time = elapsed time since the start of the study
# int = the intervention, coded 0 for pre-intervention, 1 for post-intervention
# tsi = elpased time since intervention
```

I performed a Durbin-Watson test and to correct for autocorrelation, used the `prais_winsten` function to model my rates.

[image: This is what my graph looks like]

The white area is the pre-intervention period, the grey area is the post-intervention period.

Obviously, the regression line corrected for auto-correlation seems kind of weird and doesn't seem to represent the data very well.

Is this because the analysis itself is problematic because of the lack of data points and the non-stationarity of the data?
I know that it can be problematic to assume a change point a priori, but in this case, the point of intervention is given.

Is there any better way I can approach this problem?